# ssh and window ids

Tags: linux, ssh, solaris, debian, x11

I have a project to do in school which is baffeling me...  I am SSHing into a Solaris computer in the computer lab from my own Debian box via

```
ssh -Y name@***.cs.<school>
```

I can get in just fine, and the X11 seems to be working also.  However, this peticular project requires us to find the window id of a netscape window via xwininfo and use this information in the following command

```
netscape -id 0xa00029 -remote 'openFile(/path/to/html/file)'
```

Now, if this netscape is the only window I have open (other than xterm), the preceding command works just fine.  However, if I have any other iceweasel windows open (regardless of the order in which I opened netscape/iceweasel) the command will forward to my iceweasel despite the facts that I'm running the command in my SSH session **and** the two windows have very different window ids.

All of this eventually has to go into a C program, but I can't even get it to work reliably manually!

Any ideas?

P.S.  I just saw this that may help.  When I SSHed via Cygwin/X using the same command, I get this error

```
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
```

Not sure if this is important as I can still use X11 (aparently) perfectly.

Thanks.

P.P.S  the -id switch is documented in the netscape man pages:

```
-id window-id
      Identifies an X window to receive -remote commands.  If
      you do not specify a window, the first window found is
      used.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sat down to an actual machine to perform the same tests, and they all fail there too...  I would open 2 netscape windows and try to direct the command to one at a time.  The most recently opened one would work properly, but any command directed to the other one would be forwarded to the same window, so at this point I am convinced that the problem lies in the command being not properly implemented and/or everything on that system being **really, really** old.

Answer (score 2):

When you use ssh -Y, you're requesting that remote clients be forwarded to your local X server, with full permissions. The Netscape/Mozilla/Firefox/Iceweasel/Etc. remote protocol runs through the X server, so it'll be forwarded too.

http://www.mozilla.org/unix/remote.html documents the protocol, and mentions nothing about `-id`. Nor does a very quick look at the source (e.g., http://mxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/widget/src/xremoteclient/XRemoteClient.cpp#202) look promising for there being an `-id` option.

Answer (score 0):

> if I have any other iceweasel windows
>   open (regardless of the order in which
>   I opened netscape/iceweasel) the
>   command will forward to my iceweasel
>   despite the facts that I'm running the
>   command in my SSH session and the two
>   windows have very different window ids

Iceweasel is coded that way. It tries to have only a single process run for all open windows for that user.

Use the `-no-remote` command line option to avoid it. See `http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments`